# How can I integrate these two simple javascript codes?

Tags: javascript, percentage, addition

I have a javascript code already setup to give a total. I just need to add 4% of the total to the actual total. This is what I have

```
/* EXISTING WORKING TOTAL CODE */
$(function () {
$('.DoPricing').on("keyup",function () {
    var total = 0;
    $('.DoPricing').each(function () {
        total += parseFloat($(this).val()) || 0;
    });
    $('#TotalPrice').html('$' + total);
});
});

 /* NEW PERCENTAGE CODE BELOW THAT NEEDS INTEGRATED */
 /* The code below is suppose to add 4% to total once integrated*/

 var total = round_decimals(order_total, 2);
 frm.TOTAL.value = total + ((4/100)*total);
```

Comment: Adding 4% can also be done by multiplying by 1.04. Much easier that your formula.

Comment: `frm.TOTAL.value = total*1.04;` `$('#TotalPrice').html('$' + (total*1.04));`

Comment: Where do I add that equation? I tried adding total + ((4/100)*total) myself and it just didn't work.

Comment: But actually, I don't know why you don't just put those two snippets together yourself, unless that code is not yours and you've never seen any code before and have no idea what any of this is doing.

Comment: $('#TotalPrice').html('$' + total*1.04); Worked but the decimal places are missing. Example: $105.3

Comment: I admit, i am not good at javascript. If this were PHP, I would be teaching others. But I need to study javascript!

Comment: so try below answer Phil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var total = 200;
total = total*1.04;
console.log(total); // 208
```

So in your case

```
$(function () {
 $('.DoPricing').on("keyup",function () {
    var total = 0;
    $('.DoPricing').each(function () {
        total += parseFloat($(this).val()) || 0;
    });
    $('#TotalPrice').html('$' + (total*1.04).toFixed(2));
 });
});
```

would output 208.00 for 200 as total.

Comment: This works! Thank you!!! Now to learn it, I see that I had the right idea but I didn't have syntax down nor did i know toFixed(2). Thank you!!